# Printing HMTL elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, printing

I need to print a list of elements on the click of a button. I have the data in my back-end, and am generating a table of elements with 5 elements in each row through the following:

```
const labelDataHTML = (values) => (
  <table id="dataTable" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <caption>Labels</caption>
    {_.chunk(values, 5).map((item, index) => (
      <tr key={`row-${index}`} className={`row`}>
        {index % 5 !== 0
          ? item.map((obj) => <td>{obj}</td>)
          : item.map((obj) => <td>{obj}</td>)}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </table>
);
```

I am retrieving the HTML object in another function which I am triggering on click of a button (found this code block on other SO pages):

```
const printData = (domElement) => {
  var printContents = document.querySelector("table").innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
};
```

There are 2 problems with this. 1 is that I lose all the HTML table elements upon clicking the print button, and it just becomes a long list without spaces. Second is that once I click it, all other elements on my page become unresponsive. I have attached a [sandbox][1] as well.

I'm new to React and javascript in general. Appreciate all the help!

UPDATE:
Here's how I solved the problem:
I found this solution based on a ton of other questions I found on SO:

```
const labelDataHTML = values =>
    ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <table id="dataTable" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <caption>Labels</caption>
            {_.chunk(values, 5).map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <tr className={`row`}>
                        {index % 5 !== 0
                            ? item.map(obj => <td>{obj}</td>)
                            : item.map(obj => <td>{obj}</td>)
                        }
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
        </table>
    );

const PrintLabels = labelData => {
    let domElement = labelDataHTML(labelData)
    let windowInstance = window.open("");

    windowInstance.document.write(domElement);

    windowInstance.print();
    windowInstance.close();
};
```

[1] : https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-cache-81qgu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue, you need to wrap your `printContents` within html `table` tag.

```
`<table>${printContents}</table>`
```

For your second problem, you need to create a window instance and open the print dialog in new window and then close the instance. You can refactor your function to something like this:

```
const printData = (domElement) => {
   let printContents = document.querySelector("table").innerHTML;
   let windowInstance= window.open("");
   windowInstance.document.write(`<table>${printContents}</table>`);
   windowInstance.print();
   windowInstance.close();
};
```

Comment: Hey! Accepting your answer as the correct answer. Although it was not quite what I was looking for, it put me on the right path! Thanks for replying so quick!

Answer (score 0):

You are temporarily changing the contents of the page in a way which I find to be a very hacky way to achive that.

A better way would be to hide every other element on the page only for print with css:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #dataTable,
  #dataTable * {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  #dataTable {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply print the table using:

```
window.print();
```

[image: Edit adoring-worker-tpijh]

Comment: I should have explained it better. I have a table of requests raised. Each request has multiple labels attached to it (that are generated upon the creation of the request). I'm putting a print button in the last column of that table to print the labels. This example is to print those labels, so I can't use CSS to print them, since they're never rendered on my page, only stored in state. I had not intended to change the contents of the page. Trying to figure out a way to use the generated HTML and pass it to the print function onClick